# Can't run pepper flash plugin inside my electron app

Tags: flash, plugins, electron

I try to run flash inside my electron application, so I followed next instructions from https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-pepper-flash-plugin.md and I did next steps:

1. Copy and paste from Chrome to my project directory **PepperFlashPlayer.plugin** version **27.0.0.130** (I take version from info.plist inside plugin)
2. Copy and use inside my project next code:

   ```
   let pluginName;
   switch (process.platform) {
     case 'win32':
       pluginName = 'pepflashplayer.dll';
       break;
     case 'darwin':
       pluginName = 'PepperFlashPlayer.plugin';
       break;
     case 'linux':
       pluginName = 'libpepflashplayer.so';
       break;
   }
   app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-path', path.join(__dirname, 'PepperFlashPlayer.plugin'));
   ```

and:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    fullscreen: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      plugins: true,
    }
  });
```

When I launch the application i see the next error: **You must have Adobe Flash Player 11.3.300 or higher installed in your system. Click here to visit Adobe.com now**

If I inside also `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ppapi-flash-version', '27.0.0.130')` the application says: **couldn't load plugin** inside a black screen.

`chrome://plugins` doesn't work in current chrome version. I also tried to install flash plugins (system version of flash is also 27.0 version)

Did anyone met this problem and can help me?

Comment: What site/URL did you try to visit? Does [**this link**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed) work or it also shows **exact** same error?